# Choropleth or Thematic map creation from number of points within Shapefile polygon

Tags: r, gis, spatial, shapefile

I have geocoded data points (.csv) and a shapefile (Tigerline) read into R and maps overlaying the points (locations) on the polygons (counties) all under the same projection using plot() and add=.

I am trying to find a way to map the number of points found in each polygon (county). I assume this would be a choropleth or some sort of thematic map. However associating the shapefile and the points is throwing me for a loop.

And if you can't tell, I am both an R and spatial analysis newbie

I have gotten this far:

```
count1<-table(epoints.spdf$county.NAME)
count2<-as.data.frame(count1)
county$COUNT<-count2
merge(count2$Freq, county$COUNT, by = c('Var1', 'county.NAME'))
```

I get error:

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns

My data looks like this:

```
               Var1 Freq  
1            Amelia    7  
2          Caroline   33  
3      Charles City    1  
4      Chesterfield  209  
5  Colonial Heights   26  
6         Dinwiddie   23  
7         Goochland   15  
8           Hanover   84  
9           Henrico  241  
10         Hopewell   24  
11     King William   12  
12         New Kent   23  
13       Petersburg   38  
14         Powhatan   20  
15    Prince George   18  
16         Richmond  194  
17           Sussex   16
```

SOLVED:

```
count1<-table(epoints.spdf$county.NAME)  
count2<-as.data.frame(count1)  
merge(count2, county@data, by.x = 'Var1', by.y= 'NAME')
```

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067051/how-to-add-a-column-with-location-based-data-to-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe-in-r)?

Comment: That almost works. The problem I am having is that within the points data frame, I have the county where each point is located. So basically, I can get the frequency of points within the county, but I have no knowledge as far as matching those frequencies back to the counties in the shapefile.

I am trying to find a way to total that column with the names of the counties in the points data frame and map those counts with the shapefile data frame

Comment: Looks good. I don't have your shape file, so I cannot do the merging. Does the shapefile have a column `county.NAME` in its data slot? In that case, `merge(count2, county$COUNT, by.x = 'Var1', by.y = 'county.NAME')` should do the trick. Cuttently, R complains that you specified a missing column name - probably `Var1`, because it's not part of `count2$Freq`, which is just a vector...

Comment: so I am starting to think that maybe its the shapefile data slot. The shapefile has the county.name variable. From your code, i get this:  

> merge(count2, county$COUNT, by.x = 'Var1', by.y= 'county.NAME')
Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: `county` or `county@data`, not `county$COUNT`. (The latter one is also only a vector that has no column named `county.NAME`.)

Comment: Ya. i caught it right after I sent that back.. Changing it back to county or county@data did not work. Same error as previously.     merge(count2, county@data, by.x = 'Var1', by.y= 'county.NAME')

Comment: IF `merge(count2, county@data, by.x = 'Var1', by.y= 'county.NAME')` yielded that error again, then I guess either count2 has no column Var1 (or multiple columns with the same name) or country@data has no column county.NAME. (Maybe it's called just NAME?)

Comment: GOT IT!!!!!!! you are exactly right          count1<-table(epoints.spdf$county.NAME)
count1
count2<-as.data.frame(count1)
count2
merge(count2, county@data, by.x = 'Var1', by.y= 'NAME')
names(county)
data.frame(county)