# Plotting map of county frequency counts for shapefile map and .csv file (data) in R using spplot

Tags: r, geospatial

I have a shapefile of counties (county) and a .csv file of data points (epoints) with coordinates. 
I can plot the points over the polygon using plot() and points() and have spatialpoints and spatialpointdataframes built.

I am trying to figure out how to plot frequency counts of data points by county creating a thematic or choroplethic map (legend also). All points fall within the polygons.

I had previously done over() to select only those points in the study polygons which is why you see the excess for variables in the points data set

Examples of code are below:

```
county <- readOGR(".", "RichmondMSA")
epoints<- read.csv("Richmond MSA stores.csv", header=TRUE)  
epoints.sp <- SpatialPoints(epoints [,c(3,4)])   
epoints.spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(epoints.sp, epoints, match.ID = TRUE)

plot(county, main="Stores in Richmond MSA")  
points(epoints.sp, pch=20, col=26)

 names(county)  
 [1] "STATEFP"  "COUNTYFP" "COUNTYNS"  
 [4] "GEOID"    "NAME"     "NAMELSAD"  
 [7] "LSAD"     "CLASSFP"  "MTFCC"     
[10] "CSAFP"    "CBSAFP"   "METDIVFP"  
[13] "FUNCSTAT" "ALAND"    "AWATER"    
[16] "INTPTLAT" "INTPTLON"  

> names(epoints.spdf)  
 [1] "FID"               "Score"              
 [3] "X"                 "Y"                  
 [5] "Match_addr"        "STORE.NAME"         
 [7] "ADDRESS"           "CITY"               
 [9] "STATE"             "ZIP"                           
[17] "YELP"              "county.STATEFP"     
[19] "county.COUNTYFP"   "county.COUNTYNS"    
[21] "county.GEOID"      "county.NAME"        
[23] "county.NAMELSAD"   "county.LSAD"        
[25] "county.CLASSFP"    "county.MTFCC"       
[27] "county.CSAFP"      "county.CBSAFP"      
[29] "county.METDIVFP"   "county.FUNCSTAT"    
[31] "county.ALAND"      "county.AWATER"      
[33] "county.INTPTLAT"   "county.INTPTLON"    
[35] "county.Count"      "tracts.STATEFP"     
[37] "tracts.COUNTYFP"   "tracts.TRACTCE"     
[39] "tracts.GEOID"      "tracts.NAME"        
[41] "tracts.NAMELSAD"   "tracts.MTFCC"       
[43] "tracts.FUNCSTAT"   "tracts.ALAND"       
[45] "tracts.AWATER"     "tracts.INTPTLAT"    
[47] "tracts.INTPTLON"   "tracts.FID_1"       
[49] "tracts.STATEFP_1"  "tracts.COUNTYFP_1"  
[51] "tracts.COUNTYNS"   "tracts.GEOID_1"     
[53] "tracts.NAME_1"     "tracts.NAMELSAD_1"  
[55] "tracts.LSAD"       "tracts.CLASSFP"     
[57] "tracts.MTFCC_1"    "tracts.CSAFP"       
[59] "tracts.CBSAFP"     "tracts.METDIVFP"    
[61] "tracts.FUNCSTAT_1" "tracts.ALAND_1"     
[63] "tracts.AWATER_1"   "tracts.INTPTLAT_1"  
[65] "tracts.INTPTLON_1"
```

[Points in the counties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICQsf.png)

Comment: Hmm [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259721/choropleth-or-thematic-map-creation-from-number-of-points-within-shapefile-polyg) like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067051/how-to-add-a-column-with-location-based-data-to-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe-in-r)?

Comment: That got me to editing the data slot in the shapefile, however I couldnt get the data frame to include it. i think the help I need is with spplot() also.